# play background music continuously

Tags: html, flash

I am playing a background on my webpage by using miniswfloopplayer, now I want the music to play continuously throughout the website, currently the music starts all over again when a page loads which is quite obvious. I am looking for a approach where I can avoid the above situation.

I know similar questions have been posted here, but they are inactive from a long time.

Comment: The BBC Iplayer manages something kind of like this where if you refresh the page halfway through watching or listening to a show it allows you to resumes at the same point. I presume it must just log to local storage every second or so.

Answer (score 2):

A) Please don't do it without providing an easy way to turn it off. background music is a major nuisance

B) Frames are an awful concept, but this is exactly the kind of scenario they are good for:

```
<frameset cols="5%,*">
    <frame src="music.html" /> <!-- this one always remains -->
    <frame src="content.html" /> <!-- this one changes without breaking the frameset,
     as long as you only use links with either no target or target="_SELF" -->
</frameset>
```

(sorry if there are errors in my markup, haven't used frames in about 13 years)

Comment: these frames are side by side, i need it one above the other

Comment: My Bad. I meant cols instead of rows

Comment: uh, rows instead of cols, sorry again